# Page generated by php doesn't show Google doc content in iframe, same text in html works

Tags: php, html, iframe, google-docs

My page is split in 4 sections, and each section is generated by a method of a php object.
The first section shows just a text and works well, the second and the fourth nothing (so far).

My problem is with the third section that is supposed to show an embedded Google spreadsheet.
The php page creates the correct html code, in fact the title text shows up correctly, but the iframe shows a message from Google saying that the requested file doesn't exist.

Then I press Ctrl+U to open the page source (I'm using Firefox), copy the text, paste it in a new test.html, save it to the server, open the new test.html in Firefox, and now Google likes it and the iframe shows up correctly.

Why do I have two pages with identical source, but one works and the other doesn't?

Here is the full php code for the page:

```
<?php
  $filename = "parameters-test.txt";
  $file_size = filesize($filename);
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
  fclose($handle);

  $content = str_replace('\"', '"', $content); // ??? why do I need this? And do I need only this? Isn't there some decode function?
  $alldata = json_decode($content);
  $pages = $alldata->page;
  $parameters = $alldata->parameters[0];

  $websiteTitle = $parameters->websiteTitle;

  $sheets = array();

  foreach($pages as $page) {
    $sheet = new Sheet();
    $sheet->load($page);
    array_push($sheets, $sheet);
  }

  if(isset($_GET["pageId"])) $currentSheet = $_GET["pageId"];
  else $currentSheet = 0; // this is the Welcome page

  class Sheet {
    public $definition = '';

    public function load($parameters) {
      $this->definition = $parameters;
    }

    public function showTitle() {
      echo '<h1>';
      echo $this->definition->title;
      echo '</h1>';
      echo "\n";
    }

    public function showHeader() {
      if($this->definition->heightHeader) {
        echo '<iframe width="';
        echo $this->definition->width;
        echo '" height="';
        echo $this->definition->heightHeader;
        echo '" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=';
        echo $this->definition->documentId;
        echo '&single=true&gid=';
        echo $this->definition->headerSheetId;
        echo '&output=html&widget=false&gridlines=false&range=';
        echo str_replace(':', '%3AD', $this->definition->rangeHeader);
        echo '"></iframe><br />';
        echo "\n";
      }
    }

    public function showBody() {
      echo '<iframe width="';
      echo $this->definition->width;
      echo '" height="';
      echo $this->definition->heightBody;
      echo '" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=';
      echo $this->definition->documentId;
      echo '&single=true&gid=';
      echo $this->definition->bodySheetId;
      echo '&output=html&widget=false&gridlines=false&range=';
      echo str_replace(':', '%3AD', $this->definition->rangeBody);
      echo '"></iframe><br />';
      echo "\n";
    }

    public function showLinks() {
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <title><?php echo $websiteTitle; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $sheets[$currentSheet]->showTitle();
      $sheets[$currentSheet]->showHeader();
      $sheets[$currentSheet]->showBody();
      $sheets[$currentSheet]->showLinks();
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the html generated, which only works if it comes out of a test.html, not out of a test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <title>this is the title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hotshots pool league</h1>
<iframe width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqEyi7du69LQdHRJXzViMlhEdHVYY2E4X1hnZ21EQ2c&single=true&gid=12&output=html&widget=false&gridlines=false&range=A1%3ADZ999"></iframe><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this live somewhere for testing?  I can't reproduce it - if I upload an exact copy of your html to my webserver, it works, and if I upload a simplified version in php it works too.

Comment: I closed and reopened Firefox and now it works. This is my first php page, I don't have experience with testing a page under construction. Is this some kind of cache corruption?

Comment: It's hard to say since I was never able to see the problem.  Glad it's working for you now!